# Workflow: Set field1 to CurrentItem:ModifiedBy displaying creator instead of editor

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, designer-workflow, infopath-rules

I have set an action in a SPD workflow that if field equals 1 then Set field1 to `CurrentItem:ModifiedBy` but the field has displayed the creator of the item instead of the person editing it. How could I fix this?

**PS:** I also tried creating the rule in InfoPath using `username()` but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

**This problem may occur in the following cases**

The workflow is configured to start on item created, in this case, once you add a new item the `Modified By = Created By`.

[image]

So make sure that it also started on the `Item Changed`.

[image]

---

You may be trying to edit the item with the same created user, so the result would be `Modified By = Created By` too.

---

There is a problem that has been resolved in DEC 2013 Cumulative Update that closes to the description you mentioned

**The issue**

> When you create a list workflow in which platform type is SharePoint
>   2013 workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013, the workflow may set an
>   incorrect user name in some list item fields.

Check the details at [Description of the SharePoint Server 2013 hotfix package (Sts-x-none.msp): December 10, 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2837677/description-of-the-sharepoint-server-2013-hotfix-package-sts-x-none-ms)